# Building zip file with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, teamcity

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to develop a website.  The website is on github, and I have a server for continuous integration set up with Teamcity.

I am trying to get the website to automatically deploy to AWS when I change it on github.  I have Teamcity hooked up, but the AWS CLI is having some issues, so I need to compile the solution in Teamcity into a zip file so that I can deploy to AWS using a workaround.

I've tried editing the project files for an MSBuild fix...I managed to get a zip file output.  However, I ran into problems with general compilation.

What I am wondering is, since I can publish a website package from Visual Studio, is it possible to compile as if I was publishing using the build commands from TeamCity (or the command line) so that the result is the compiled project and the website files needed to run the site in a zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a zipped artifact in TeamCity. Simply build the project then set the artifacts for the build like this:

```
outputFolder\*.dll=>myzipfile.zip
outputFolder\*.whatever=>myzipfile.zip
etc
```

obviously you'll need to change outputFolder to be where the files are actually output by the build and the patterns to macth the files you want